# git: 'reflow' is not a git command. See 'git --help'

Tags: git, github

Error:

```
git reflow
git: 'reflow' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
    reflog git reflow command is not recognised,
```

I have installed both git and `git_reflow` gem and even tried uninstalling and reinstalling the reflow and     updating the git version.

Current versions installed are :

```
git_reflow 0.7.1,
git version 2.6.3,
ruby 2.2.3p173
```

https://github.com/reenhanced/gitreflow

Comment: Then reflow is an extension that is 'not found', ie. what does `which git-reflow` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `git reflow` to work, you need to have after installation an executable `git-reflow` somewhere in your PATH.

Check that your PATH does include where `gem install git_reflow` install those modules.